# Docker File: Chmod on Entrypoint Script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a reason I need to chmod +x on my entrypoint script? It didn't appear Redis was doing this in their dockerfile (https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/109323988b7663bceaf4a01c3353f8934dfc002e/2.8/Dockerfile) for their entrypoint script.

Dockerfile:

```
# Generic Docker Image for Running Node app from Git Repository
FROM    node:0.10.33-slim
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add script to pull Node app from Git and run the app
COPY docker-node-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["--help"]
```

Answer (score 17):

Docker will copy files into the container with the permissions of their source. If you strip the Linux executable bits somewhere in the chain of pushing to your code repo, or on your build host, then you'll need to add those execute permissions back. I've seen this issue most often reported by Windows users, who are downloading code to a filesystem that doesn't support the Linux permission bits. Hopefully we'll get a [`COPY --chmod` solution soon that will eliminate the need for an extra layer](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34819).

Comment: `COPY --chmod` is now possible (since Docker v20.10). See [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/1492). Just note that, as of now, this change is [not yet reflected](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2941) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 16):

redis don't need to do it because their script already have exec flag:

```
~/redis/2.8$ ls -l docker-entrypoint.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 igor igor 109 Dec  3 23:52 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

if you will do it for your docker-node-entrypoint.sh script you would not need chmod in Dockerfile too.

This is possible because the git core.fileMode option by default is true, so the executable bit of a file is honored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

it have worked for me